# Is there a way to enable gpu for tensorflowlite for android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way to enable gpu for tensorflowlite for android? I am using inceptionv3 pretrained model with tensorflow lite in android but it takes about 1-1.5 seconds to inference. I checked the android neural network api but it supports only android 8.1 onwards.

Comment: I met the same problem. I've tried TensorFlow Lite and found it's faster. But the conversion from pb to tflite with toco is difficult to me.

Comment: i can help you with that if you have specific question regarding the conversion. i have spent hours working with it.

Comment: Not yet, but we're working on it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, most of Android phones in the market have Qualcomm Chipsets with Adreno GPU.
The interface for Adreno GPU is not yet supported by Qualcomm which means that even if you convert your model to tflite, most of the speedup you get is from Neon optimization and not from GPU.
There are plans to support DSP for the next generation of phones but so far there are no phones in the market that support tflite with Qualcomm DSP (HVX).
Hope this helps.